# MYSQL Explain 'Using:where; Using temporary; Using filesort'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to optimize a stored procedure. I have identified some issues with it, but I don't know enough to actually correct the problems. One of the subqueries looks like this

```
select  d.districtCode,
        b.year Year,
        if(bli.releaseAdjustment = 3 and bli.id not in (select billLineItem_id from AppliedDiscount), 
        bli.amount ,0) *-1 Refund
from Bill b 
join BillLineItem bli on bli.bill_id = b.id 
left join Bill_District d on d.bill_id = b.id 
    and bli.type = d.type
left join AppliedDiscount a on a.billLineItem_id = bli.id
where bli.releaseAdjustment in (1,2,3)         
and bli.type in (4,6) 
group by d.districtCode, b.year
```

The `EXPLAIN`  outputs this

```
+----+------------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type            | table         | type         | possible_keys                  | key             | key_len | ref                 | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+------------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY                | bli           | ALL          | FKF4236A,type,releaseAdjustment| NULL            | NULL    | NULL                | 2787322 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | PRIMARY                | b             | eq_ref       | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY         | 8       | tax.bli.bill_id     |    1    |                                              | 
|  1 | PRIMARY                | d             | ref          | bill_id,type                   | bill_id         | 8       | tax.bli.bill_id     |    1    |                                              | 
|  1 | PRIMARY                | a             | ref          | billLineItem_idx               | billLineItem_idx| 8       | tax.bli.id          |    1    | Using index                                  | 
|  1 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY     |AppliedDiscount|index_subquery| billLineItem_idx               | billLineItem_idx| 8       | func                |    1    | Using index                                  | 
+----+------------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

How would you suggest I fix this? This problem, or one very similar, is found throughout this stored procedure numerous times. `AppliedDiscount` only consists of 3 columns, all of which are indexed already.

Edit: Removing the `group by` changes the first row of the explain to

```
|  1 | PRIMARY                | bli           | ALL          | FKF4236A,type,releaseAdjustment,bill_id| NULL            | NULL    | NULL                | 2613847 | Using where |
```

That's better and technically answers my question, but that just means that I was asking the wrong question.
The 'type' is still ALL. What can I do to improve that?

Comment: What's the purpose of a group by without any aggregation?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. This query is a subquery and is ```union all``` to other subqueries.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad question, just that I don't know enough to understand what you're asking.

Comment: @P.Salmon Removing the ```group by``` changes the first row of the explain. 
That's better and technically answers my question, but that just means that I was asking the wrong question.
The 'type' is still ALL. What can I do to improve that?

Comment: queries that use `IN` often suffer in performance, try eliminating them using left joins, or temporary tables. you are using `IN` three times, oof